# How does Ruby webdriver get element with hyphen in <name, value> pair

Tags: ruby, webdriver

I have HTML like below and I want to get the element by "sku-code" (there is a hyphen in it)

```
<div class="leavemessagebox" style="position: relative;" sku-code="m_showcase">
```

When I used

```
browser.div(:sku-code=>'m_showcase')
```

Ruby reported an error

```
ERROR:undefined local variable or method `code' for #<AUT::WebClient:0x2c59650>
```

It sames Ruby can't recognize "sku-code" as a name, anyone can give me any suggestion about how to get the element by "sku-code"?
Sorry for not explain myself clearly. There are many elements that have sku-code selector and I want to collect them all in a list, so the class name and tag name isn't stable. How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Watir WebDriver. Try use css (preferred) or xpath.

```
browser.element(:css => "[sku-code='m_showcase']") # single one
browser.elements(:css => "[sku-code='m_showcase']") # a list of all matches
```

Documention on CSS's attribute selector is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

So basically the above selector finds all elements with attribute `sku-code` equals to `m_showcase`.

Comment: Not `:xpath` ... only `:css` I would prefer in this case. :))) anyway *+1*. Give him also the CSS selector links for reference.

Comment: @Priti: Why no `:xpath` in this case? I mean apparently `:css` is preferred here, but any reasons for the strong objection to `:xpath`?

Comment: *I mean apparently :css is preferred here* -- I feel the same like you that's why. No objection with `:xpath`. But ***CSS*** selectors has the built in functions for this type of situations,which are great to look. :)))

Comment: Sorry for not explain myself clearly. there are many elements that have sku-code selector and I want to collect them all in a list, so the class name and tag name isn't stable. how can i do that

Comment: @user1177636: Sorry, not. Can I get it without class value "leavemessagebox"

Comment: @user2256777: Yes, sure. As I explained it above, I assume you want class name AND sku-code, but if you don't want to, just remove `.leavemessagebox`. I'll update it for you.

Comment: @user1177636: Thank you very much, it solved my problem. it can be useful to any other user-defined attributes too. and Thank you for nice documention.

Comment: @user2256777: No worries. Another CSS selector tutorial you can have a look at if you have time. [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Answer (score 0):

`:sku-code` is not a valid symbol literal. It *is* however valid Ruby code, it is parsed as:

```
:sku - code
```

So, you are trying to call a method named `code` and subtracting its return value from the symbol `:sku`, which obviously doesn't make sense.

But you can quote the symbol literal, of course:

```
:'sku-code'
```

Comment: By the way: this is *extremely* basic Ruby syntax that should be covered within the first couple of minutes of every Ruby tutorial or course. It is completely unrelated to WatiR.

Comment: Yes, as you said, but it didn't sovle the problem,Thank you any way,

Answer (score 0):

browser.element(:css => ".leavemessagebox[sku-code='m_showcase']") I think this will still the specific CSS.

Please Let me know is the above CSS is working or Not.