# I can not locate proper element - click on link Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I tried to click on link (see screenshots)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/paRhC.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1sXy.jpg

I tried using few examples 
e.g

```
@browser.button(:class=> '//*[@class="login"]//ul/li[0]/a').click
```

and

```
browser.button(:xpath=> "//a[@data-viewmodel='PagesAsync/RegisterPrivate/RegisterPrivateViewModel']").click
```

but is not correct
I can see the message that unable to locate element
Can somebody help?

Comment: Please add the appropriate but minimal amount of HTML (to reproduce the issue) to the original question.  Screenshots and code in comments make it more difficult to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.  One is get your developers to add better IDs.
If that is not possible, try this:
[how does ruby webdriver get element with hyphen in <name, value> pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612497/how-does-ruby-webdriver-get-element-with-hyphen-in-name-value-pair)
It worked for me in several similar situations.

Comment: thanks but truly said I do not know how can I use this for my example;( with link that u added. First option is impossible ;)

Comment: @pav, out of curiosity, what did you end up doing to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are telling Watir to look for a `button` when you actually want a `link`. While the UI may be styled to look like a button, you will notice that the HTML has a `a` tag instead.

The first example, which also has the wrong locator type, should be:

```
@browser.link(:xpath => '//*[@class="login"]//ul/li[0]/a').click
```

The second example should be:

```
browser.link(:xpath => "//a[@data-viewmodel='PagesAsync/RegisterPrivate/RegisterPrivateViewModel']").click
```

Note that the second example would be more Watir-like if you use the normal attribute locators:

```
browser.link(data_viewmodel: 'PagesAsync/RegisterPrivate/RegisterPrivateViewModel').click
```

Comment: hi thanks, but still the same;/ for this 3 examples and for another link works with button not link ;))

Comment: Please provide the HTML that reproduces the problem.

Comment: <a data-bind="click: open.bind(null, $parent.redirectTo)" data-initobject="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Registrering&quot;,&quot;salesConditionsTitle&quot;:&quot;Salgsbetingelser&quot;}" data-viewmodel="PagesAsync/RegisterPrivate/RegisterPrivateViewModel" href="#">For priva</a>

and here screen with more code: http://imgur.com/mFvqQeV

Comment: That HTML isn't sufficient to reproduce your problem. If you create a page with just that HTML, the last 2 examples work correctly. This means there is something more complicated with your problem. Without the HTML (and likely JavaScript/CSS), we cannot reproduce that issue. If you cannot create an example, then all I can suggest is that you work through the [common reasons for seeing this exception](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/).

Comment: I added @browseer.a(:xpath,"//a[@data-viewmodel='PagesAsync/RegisterPrivate/RegisterPrivateViewModel']").click but now another error occurs: oMethodError: undefined method `a' for nil:NilClass

Comment: What is `@browseer`? Is that actually your browser instance? Based on your original examples, it should be `@browser` (notice one "e" instead of 2) or `browser`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you can find a button by using an xpath to a link. It is also not clear whether you use browser or @browser. You would need to look into how the browser instance is defined, which likely is one of these:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
###or###
browser = Watir::Browser.start 'example.com', :firefox
```

and if you haven't create a browser instance, then you would need to do it before you can use Watir-Webdriver. ;)

As for your question, you could try searching using the text if it is unique like this, though it may be a brittle test:

```
@browser.div(:class => 'login').link(:text => /For priva/).click
```

but I would recommend to double check the number of elements found using the div and link locators like this to make sure you got the right element:

```
@browser.divs(:class => 'login').length
@browser.div(:class => 'login').links(:text => /For priva/).length
```

Comment: thanks! but still does not work..;:( unable to locate element, using {:class=>"login", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException). I think that instead of first line (divs) should be div? than I got "method_missing': undefined method `length' for #<Watir::Div:0x00000002c85800> (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Watir::Div does not have a length method, but Watir::DivCollection does. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/ElementCollection#length-instance_method     The error you get indicates that Watir cannot find the div container with class name 'login'. Has the HTML stayed the same?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link in the previous comment: http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/DivCollection . What happens if you try @browser.div(:class => 'ubo-box scroll').div(:class => 'login').ul.lis[0].a.text and @browser.div(:class => 'ubo-box scroll').div(:class => 'login').ul.lis[0].a.present?